# Combine CKEditor into 1 file

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Thought I would open this question to the  javascript community. Does anyone know if its possible to combine CKEditor into 1 file? I want to try and integrate it in one of my desktop applications which uses a web viewer - I can execute one flat file in my web viewer internally in my application otherwise I'll have to reference to the CDN which I'm hoping to avoid. I want to develop an app that does not require external web service.

Performance should not be an issue as the file would be in my application running locally - I would include all the licenses/readme etc etc.

Is there a tool out there that can help me to achieve this, and has anyone done it or is not possible due to the architecture - the way CKEditor has been written?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor loads some JS files on demand (i.e. dialog definitions). There are also several skin CSS files, sprites with icons and separate langfiles. I hardly think there's any reasonable way to combine all these resources into a working JS bundle without architectural changes.

Comment: Thanks Oleq for the reply, I'm coming to the same conclusion after reading up other posts on the various forums.

Comment: You can find here more details about how CKEditor is minified. Maybe they will shed some additional light - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301099/ckeditor-4-build-minify-and-uglify/15305081#15305081