# Is there a way to build release version of CKEditor unminified

Tags: ckeditor

I've cloned the source repo from [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev), and I want to build everything into one file, but don't want this file to be uglified. Is there any settings I need to tweak in the build files to prevent uglification? I've tried searching for `uglify` or `minify` in the project files but have found nothing.

Comment: Check the built-in help of CKBuilder for any configuration options available. As suggested in the [builder documentation](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckbuilder), run the builder with `--help` | `--build-help` | `--full-help`.

Comment: @AnnaTomanek, thanks a lot, I've found the option I was looking for using `--help`. I added answer the this question for future reference if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following build property prevents minification:

```
--leave-js-unminified
```

It could be added to the `dev/build.sh` config here:

```
java -jar ckbuilder/$CKBUILDER_VERSION/ckbuilder.jar --build ../../ release $JAVA_ARGS --version="$VERSION" --revision="$REVISION" --overwrite --leave-js-unminified
```